# Array aparece cómo tipo de dato objeto - Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un problema con un Array en Node Js (JS) el cuál es devuelto como array pero **tipo de dato Objeto**, algo muy raro que nunca me había pasado.

Tengo una clase en llamada `Conversation`
con el siguiente constructor, la propiedad que importa es: `this.users` que es un Array

```
constructor() {
    this.readDB();
    this.users = [];
}
```

Y tengo dos métodos `connectUser, disconnectUser`

```
 connectUser( user ){
    this.users.unshift(user);
}

disconnectUser( id ){
    const current = this.users.findIndex( user => user.id === id);
    this.users.splice(current, 1);
}
```

Todo funciona bien, se agrega el usuario y se quita cuando se llaman los métodos en las instancias de la clase, pero al ver en consola el resultado todo sigue igual, es un Array pero... al ver el `typeof de esa propiedad` aparece como `object`y eso me da problemas en mi frontend, no entiendo por qué sucede esto, literalmente llevo horas buscando y viendo el código.

Esto aparece en consola: 
 
[image: Output de consola]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Comment: Un array por defecto es tipo `object` en cualquier circunstancia natural de Javascript, lo puedes comprobar con `typeof []; // object`, para reconocer un array usa [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: Justo como menciona @anythingg, JavaScript no tiene un [tipo de dato](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) específico para referirse a un array, pues en la documentación se especifíca que [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) es un **objeto** global utilizado para la contrucción de arrays los cuales son **objetos de tipo lista**.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra reservada `typeof` sólo sirve para distinguir entre tipos primitivos y objetos. Un array es un tipo de objeto, por tanto queda en el grupo de los objetos:

```js
class MiClase {
  constructor() {
    this.parametro = 'Mi clase';
  }
}

const instancia = new MiClase();
const datos = [
  1,
  'texto',
  true,
  { param: 'test'},
  new String('1'), // String !== string
  instancia
];

datos.forEach(dato => console.log('El dato', dato, 'es del tipo', typeof dato));
console.log('Un array es del tipo', typeof datos);

console.log('¿Es datos un array?', datos instanceof Array);
console.log('¿Es instancia de la clase MiClase?',instancia instanceof MiClase);
```

Como ves, para comprobar si un objeto es una instancia de una clase en particular, puedes usar `instanceof`

Comment: Creo que en el primer `console.log` inmediatamente después del foreach tienes un typo. Tienes `dato` en lugar de `datos` por lo que la salida es `undefined` en lugar de `object`. A menos que el propósito haya sido diferente al de mostrar que un array es de tipo object.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc gracias

Comment: Wow! bastante claro, muchisimas gracias!